# Django ORM - Translate this self join query to ORM

Tags: python, mysql, django, orm

Please help translate this SQL query to Django ORM query.

```
select l.* from products l inner join products r on l.category = r.category where r.id = %s
```

Please note that `category` is itself a ForeignKey that points to `ProductCategory` Model (telling in case it's useful for you). Also, if possible combine this with this ORM query.

```
Product.objects.prefetch_related('productrecipes', 'farmerprofiles', 'productfeedbacks')
```

Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you want all the products from the same category as a given `Product`:

```
 # given product
 product = Product.objects.get(...)
 # products from same category
 related_products = Product.objects.filter(category_id=product.category_id)
```

You can then just append your `prefetch_related` calls:

```
 related_products = related_products.prefetch_related(...)
```